# What does EL5 and EL6 means in term of packages?

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm

I am using CentOS with Citrix XenServer.

```
[root@xen01 shm]# uname -a
Linux xen01 2.6.32.43-0.4.1.xs1.8.0.855.170800xen #1 SMP Mon Jul 21 05:12:35 EDT 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

[root@xen01 shm]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: XenServer
Description:    XenServer release 6.2.0-70446c (xenenterprise)
Release:    6.2.0-70446c
Codename:   xenenterprise
```

I installed apcupsd package, from http://sourceforge.net/projects/apcupsd/files/rpms%20-%20Stable/3.14.10/apcupsd-3.14.10-1.el5.i386.rpm/download

But there was a new version the past year, and seems that RPM wasn't updated to 3.14.12.

I found this version however: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-EPEL-2014-4191/apcupsd-3.14.12-1.el6

I would like to know what exactly EL5 and EL6 means in term of packages. The latter fails because of dependencies, but am I able to instal EL6 packages?

Comment: Enterprise Linux 5 and Enterprise Linux 6 - corresponding to CentOS 5 and CentOS 6, I believe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EL5 stands for Enterprise Linux 5 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux version or CentOS version) and EL6 accordingly for Enterprise Linux 6.

You can find the current release you are running in:

`cat /etc/redhat-release`

*or*

`cat /etc/centos-release`

Depending on the version your system is running with you are able to install the packages.

Comment: cat: /etc/redhat_release: No such file or directory. What happens if I install a EL6 package (or try) into a EL5? Is it like Ubuntu where packages from 12.04 could work on previous releases?

Comment: Yes! (In case you don't have a /etc/redhat_release try /etc/centos_release).

Comment: It doesn't exists neither... I think Citrix supresses all those things. Anyway I will try to build the package in Centos 5 i386. Hope I make it lol

Comment: Isn't that a dash instead of an underscore? cat /etc/redhat-release

Comment: Both ```cat /etc/centos-release``` and ```cat /etc/redhat-release``` worked on my CentOS release 6.6 server. Note the dash, not underscore.

Answer (score 4):

If you still can't find your version with [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177941/205892), you can try this:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```